# how to get all uncommitted messages in kafka when manually committing offset

Tags: java

In my application ,i am consuming json messages from kafka topic and Multiple instances are running of my application. I have set kafka prop as: props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false")
So When i consume message ,i push it to my DB and then commit it as :

```
private static void commitMessage(KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer, ConsumerRecord message, String kafkaTopic) {

    long nextOffset = message.offset() + 1;
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(kafkaTopic, message.partition());
    OffsetAndMetadata offsetAndMetadata = new OffsetAndMetadata(nextOffset);

    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsetAndMetadataMap = new HashMap<>();
    offsetAndMetadataMap.put(topicPartition, offsetAndMetadata);
    //
    log.info("Commiting processed kafka message, topic [" + kafkaTopic + "], partition [" + message.partition() + "], next offset [" + nextOffset + "]");
    kafkaConsumer.commitSync(offsetAndMetadataMap);
}
```

Now it may happen after consuming message(but before pushing it to DB) my Application restarts for some reason. Now i want to consume uncommitted message again from kafka after restart. I am able to do using seek:

```
private static void seekAllPartitions(KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer, String kafkaTopic) {

    List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfos = kafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(kafkaTopic);
    println 'Size ofpartition list : ' + partitionInfos.size()
    for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : partitionInfos) {
        TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(kafkaTopic, partitionInfo.partition());
        OffsetAndMetadata committedForPartition = kafkaConsumer.committed(topicPartition);

        try {
            if (committedForPartition != null) {
                println 'Seeking offset...' + committedForPartition.offset()
                kafkaConsumer.seek(topicPartition, committedForPartition.offset());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

Now problem is - seek(topicPartition,committedForPartition.offset()) gives me last uncommitted message and not the intermediate uncommitted messages.As i mentioned ,multiple instance are running - i may end up with intermediate uncommitted messages for ex : Instance a -2nd msg was not committed and Instance b - 5 the msg not committed but it gives me 5th message only and not 2nd.